# Why is Regex Group Extraction Giving Wrong Answer?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the Number for an Integer number (No Decimal exist),
or the number part before the Decimal Point for a Decimal Number.

The example below should give 12345 as the answer. But it is giving it as 1234 (eating the 5 out)

```
            string isDecimalTypeNumbers = @"^(?<wholeNumberPart>[0-9]*)\.?[0-9]+?$";
            Regex pattern = new Regex(isDecimalTypeNumbers);
            Match match = pattern.Match("12345");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string wholeNumberPartWithoutPlusMinusSign = match.Groups["wholeNumberPart"].Value;
                MessageBox.Show(wholeNumberPartWithoutPlusMinusSign);
            }
```

Comment: It is giving 1234  please try it yourself. I need the integer number if it is an integer number, or the integer part for a decimal number.

Comment: My bad! I misunderstood the question at first. Use `^(?<wholeNumberPart>[0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]+)?$` instead. This makes the whole "decimal part" optional.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed you are correct. I need to group the decimal part as that is also optional.

Comment: What is the ?: in (?:\.[0-9]+) when we already have a ? at the end for the entire bracket (?:\.[0-9]+)?

Comment: It's called a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/8967612).

Comment: Thanx Ahmed. One more important thing - Why does Regex give Match Success if Value String is Empty?

Comment: Just tried an empty string and, for me, `Match match = pattern.Match("");` yields `match.Success == False`.

Comment: If you don't want an empty string to match, try `^(?<wholeNumberPart>[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/yPR3lK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The decimal separator (`\.?`) is optional, so it may not match.
- The fractional part (`[0-9]+?`) is **not optional, but lazy**, so it will still try to match.

So, what could happen is 1234 is consumed by the whole number part, and `\.?` doesnt match, but 5 is consumed by the fractional part.

You should make the decimal separator and the fractional part into one optional group:

```
@"^(?<wholeNumberPart>[0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?$"
```

Comment: Thanx Xiaoy. I tried this (the same as @AhmedAbdelhameed recommended) and it worked. Thanx.

Comment: Why does Regex give Match Success if Value String is Empty?

Comment: Just change the `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+`. The `*` matches 0-to-many elements, so nothing is also a valid match. Replacing it with `+` will make it matches 1-to-many elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?<wholeNumberPart>[0-9]*)
```

captures the first part of the number

```
\.?
```

captures the decimal point *if it exists*

```
[0-9]+?$
```

captures the last number regardless of whether there is a decimal point

So as you can see the last bit captures the 5 leaving only 1234 as the wholeNumberPart.

I think this explains **why the regex group extraction is giving you the wrong answer** of 1234

Comment: thanx shac. But still why should (?<wholeNumberPart>[0-9]*) not capture the last digit 5, because after all 12345 is a whole number without any decimals.

Comment: If `[0-9]*` were to match `12345` then there'd be no digits left for `[0-9]+?` to match.  As [@Xiaoy312's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014622/150605) says, `+?` is lazy but not optional, so `[0-9]+?` must match at least one digit.

Comment: Got it @bacon. Your explanation makes it clearer. Thanx.

Comment: Why does Regex give Match Success if Value String is Empty?